# Flutter consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes not defined error?

Tags: http, flutter, dart, imageurl, uint8array

I'm trying to parse a url image in order to turn it into Uint8 bytes and share across my share provider.  When trying to consolidate my http response into bytes I get the following error `The method 'consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes' isn't defined` by my class.  Here is the code I'm trying to use.....  Please help!

```
 Future<Null> shareImage() async{
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('network_image_url'));
    var response = await request.close();
    Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import this :

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

And you should be good